# How to get access to the Spring-boot actuator JSON payload

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I m working on a customized health check for an API. Where I m using :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

and implementing the HealthIndicator interface.
I m wondering if there is a way to get access to the payload returned by /actuator/health ?
so I can desterilize it, and base on the values on the object (payload), I will build the implementation for the heath() method from HealthIndicator Interface.

I have tried to use:
- HealthEndpoint but it needs an implementation for HealtContributorRegistary , not sure how to do that.
- SystemHealth (im getting the  error : class Cannot be accessed from outside package).

any help is very welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to redact some information that Spring Boot returns in the /actuator/health response? By default, Spring Boot [`never` returns health details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.health).

Comment: Thank you for your replay,  I only need to get the status returned by actuator

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get access to all my API components status by

```
@Autowired HealthContributor[] healthContributors;
```

in a service.
I have followed this answer : [Direct access to Spring Boot Actuator Health beans/data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60741596/direct-access-to-spring-boot-actuator-health-beans-data/65484572#65484572)